# Unix process name from pid

Tags: unix, process, pipe

I believe what I am going to asked, will not be possible. Still trying to find if there is a way or approach that I wont be aware of.

I got a broken pipe error where I am having pid of destination process  but not the name. Is there any way, I can find out the process name (which possibly already terminated) using pid.

Comment: You can find the name of processes that still exist. But if it has terminated and its parent has called `wait()` to reap it, it no longer exists and you can't find out its name.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said in his comment, this isn't possible normally.  The system forgets all information about processes as soon as they terminate.

But of course your processes might be able to comply in order to help you find out more.  In case you can modify the processes in question you can let them log their PID into a special place where you can look up later which PID belonged once to which process.

This won't work for programs you cannot modify, though.  In these cases it still might be possible to put a wrapper around them which first logs the PID and then `exec`s to the wanted program.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$$: $*" >> /home/alfe/var/pid.log
exec "$@"
```

In case you are neither starting the program in question nor can you modify it, you are out of options I fear.